# How can I reload my OS X keychains?

Tags: macos, keychain

I have some (OS X) keychains stored on another computer on my local network which I've added in Keychain Access. However, sometimes when I log in these keychains are not loaded correctly, presumably because the network drive is not mounted at that point (the drive is mounted over AFP if that is relevant).

Is there any way to reload the keychains?
Or is there a way to ensure the drive is mounted before the keychains are loaded?

Comment: I assume you are talking about an OSX system, right? If yes edit your question and add this important information and correct the tags.

Comment: @Robert Good point, I've amended the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to unload and reload the keychain is by using the "lock keychain" and "unlock keychain" function. To get there, open Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access. Go to Preferences (Cmd-,) and on the General tab check "Show keychain status in menu bar".

Now a small symbol representing a lock shows up in your menu bar. This menu offers "Protect Keychain", after using this, your keychain will be locked. If you open the menu again, you can klick on "Unlock Keychain" to unlock your keychain again. This might open a dialog requesting your keychain password. After entering it, your keychain will be reloaded.